# Skype for business android SDK issue, Failed to load native library

Tags: android, aar, skype-for-business, android-native-library

I am trying to implement an app using Skype for Business Android SDK's

this is the document that helps to configure the SDK, which didn't help me integrating the aar files. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/gettingstarted

so, i integrated the libraries using new module --> import jar/aar files, that resolves my compilation error, i can now also get the class references from these SDK's. but when i run my application it says Failed to load native library.

there is an [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/HealthcareApp) on github that uses Skype for business SDK. where everything works like a charm. but i am still unable to figure out why it fails to load library in my application.

Does this **Unspecified** in my attached screenshot has to do anything with why my app is failing to load libaries?

[image: Why this library is showing as unspecified?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly adding Architecture specific Native libraries helped me.
SFB currently supports only armeabi.

1) create a folder in your project's main ***lib/armeabi***

2) Extract Sfb library marked in yellow in the pic below.

3) Navigate to ***SkypeForBusinessNative/jni/armeabi***

4) you will find five **.so** files, marked in white in the pic.

5) paste them in the folder you created in step 1.

You will have your application running.

[image]